# how to make a tool to import images in QtDesigner?

Tags: python, image, pyqt5, qt-designer

I want to make a button where I can choose a image from a folder and afterwards display it in a window. I hope the picture helps to unterstand my problem.

[image]

Comment: What you're asking is related to the *logic* of your program, Designer is only used for the UI elements. Create a window with a QPushButton and a QLabel, save the ui, then follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) to know how to generate an output file with pyuic **and how to properly use it** and implement your code logic on **a new** new script that will import it (really, use a *new script*, don't ever try to edit the contents of a pyuic generated file, it's considered very **bad** practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will give you an idea of what to do, first of all you can use any library to read images, I use OpenCV because I later process the images, in my case I read a folder with a set of images but the concept is the same for an image. You must do two things:

First:
Associate a button to a method that executes a file browser, in my case I used the one provided by the TK library but there are many more.

Second:
That path provided by the file_browser is used to load the image, then this image is associated to a label of the GUI the way to do it is specified in the view_image method.

That is basically the idea, you must read the documentation and adapt this to your application.

```
import sys
import cv2
import select
import os
import pathlib
import shutil
from imutils import paths
import pickle

from PyQt5 import uic, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt,QSize
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIntValidator,QDoubleValidator
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox,QListWidgetItem

from tkinter import filedialog
from imutils import paths
from operator import itemgetter, attrgetter

qtCreatorFile = "GUI.ui" 

Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)

class MyApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    
    def __init__(self):

        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.get_path_image_button.clicked.connect(self.get_images_dataset)
        self.view_image_button.clicked.connect(self.view_image)
        self.path_image = ''

    def get_images_dataset(self):
        root = Tk()
        root.withdraw()
        root.folder_name =  filedialog.askdirectory(
            title = 'Choose the directory of the input files'
            )

        self.path_dataset =root.folder_name
        if (root.folder_name):
            self.textBrowser.setText(
                '[INFO] Image directory path successfully uploaded'
                )
        else:
            self.textBrowser.setText(
                '[WARNING] No valid route selected'
                )
        root.destroy()

    def view_image(self):
        image_path = self.path_image 
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image_path, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        height, width, channel = image.shape
        step = channel * width
        qImg = QImage(image.data, width, height, step, QImage.Format_RGB888)
        self.image_label.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(qImg))
```

**An example:**

Obviously, this result does not correspond to the attached code, but it serves as an example.

[image]

Comment: it feels weird to mix tkinter and qt.

Comment: Yes, it is better to use QFileDialog. I just put the code that I had on hand

Comment: @Andrewgmz Why do you use opencv to show images if Qt can do it? To display an image in QLabel just: `self.image_label.setPixmap(QPixmap(image_path))`

Comment: I use opencv to process the images, that is only a part of the code, before I apply a series of filters to the images and the application as such finds the prominent objects in the image. But it is correct, if you only want to show the image in the gui, using opencv is not necessary. Just that the question was not very specific and I decided to give an idea.